# System.Timers.Timer on Mac with Mono

Tags: c#, macos, winforms, mono

I have a C# windows application that I am trying to run on a Mac OSx machine with mono framework. The application crashes occasionally without giving any helpful info on the mac console. I am extensively using System.Timers.Timer and wanted to know if this could be an issue on Mac.

Below is the basic log information. The full log is too big to be pasted here.
Please let me know if I can provide any specific information.

> Process:               mono-sgen32 [29326]
>
> Path:                  /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.6.0/bin/mono
>
> Identifier:            mono-sgen32
>
> Version:               ???
>
> Code Type:             X86 (Native)
>
> Parent Process:        XamarinStudio [28954]
>
> Responsible:           mono-sgen32 [29326]
>
> User ID:               501
>
> Date/Time:             2016-09-26 14:37:16.704 +0530
>
> OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.6 (15G1004)
>
> Report Version:        11
>
> Anonymous UUID:        652F29CC-D5AD-9992-CEE7-F959B4B17679
>
> Time Awake Since Boot: 600000 seconds
>
> System Integrity Protection: disabled
>
> Crashed Thread:        0  tid_50b  Dispatch queue:
>   com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
>
> Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000070
>
> Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
>
> VM Regions Near 0x70:
>   --> 
>       __TEXT                 0000000000100000-000000000044f000 [ 3388K] r-x/rwx SM=COW 
>   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.6.0/bin/mono-sgen32

Comment: It will crash with logs. Dig into that instead of guessing.

Comment: has the crash a stacktrace? please add more information to this question or it will be downvoted and closed

Comment: The basic crash log is added to the question. Please let me know if I can provide any specific information.